# finding the character in a file by position, then deleting all instances of said character in the file

Tags: bash, python

I have an index for a character in a string in Python (the string is just the contents of a file), and I would like to run a bash command to look up what that character is, and using that I'd like to delete all instances of it in the file. I know how to run a bash command in Python, I just would like some guidance on what the bash command should be.

PS:

The reason I'd like to use a bash command (I'm thinking awk or sed, though I don't have much experience with them, and I'm learning more about them as I write this) is because I do not want to (or really cannot) open the files in Python. Why? Because the files have different types of encodings, so let's say I open a file in utf-8 and there's some character that cannot be interpreted. Then what I do is, using the exception that was raised, I extract the position of the offending character, and plan on using that (and sed or awk perhaps) to delete the character from the file in question. Here is the code I have so far:

```
spam_emails = []

for file in os.listdir('spam'):
    error = True
    while (error):
        try:
            with open(os.path.join('spam', file), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                spam_emails.append(f.read())
            error = False
        except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
            error_msg = str(e)
            offending_char_pos = (re.search('in position \d+', error_msg).group(0)).split(" ")[-1]
            # do something to delete offending character using bash command
```

The reason for the while loop is to make sure I cover all offending characters in a given file, not just the first one.
Also, the regex is used to extract the position of the offending character from the error message of the exception, which is, for example:
:`'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 1029: invalid continuation byte`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does this help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276851/show-character-at-position-in-a-file

Comment: bash isn't a text processing / editing utility - since you're almost certainly going to need to call some other program to do that, why not do the whole thing in python?

Comment: @steeldriver the reason is because I do not want to open and read the files in Python. I'll add in some details above to explain the use case. Maybe you could then tell me if using a bash command is appropriate